# Shadow catcher not working?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, node-editor

I have made a car model and i'm ready to render , I decided to try to make a shadow catcher plane ( which has never worked )

Im using and HDRI image and set up the nodes correctly , yet it still doesn't work.

[image]

Comment: This took me a long time to figure out. There are several Q&A posts on the site already that address this, you should check them out.

Comment: I have checked several times everywhere and nothing works.

Comment: I hate to say it, but you must be doing something wrong. If I can remember how to do this, I'll post an answer here too.

Comment: Gladly appreciated, I give up i don't know what is wrong

Comment: I'm guessing this because HDR backgrounds don't cast shadows on the shadow pass yet.

Comment: Troubleshooting tip. Pick one element that you think is the problem and remove (or substitute) it. This is a lighting related problem, start with changing the lighting. Disble the HDRI and just use a spotlight - simple, fast to test. Does the shadow catcher work? I'd also test another more complex light (hemisphere, sunsky) just to see if it only suports simpler lights.

Comment: Ok so getting rid of the HDRI makes it work perfect!, But the problem is i need the HDRI for the final render! What would be a work around to enable the HDRI?

Edit : I can enable HDRI , but it can only be seen on reflections! How can i make it visible in the background?

Answer (score 0):

As said in the comments you cannot use HDRIs to cast shadows but the reflections are still showing up. You can't render the first layer without that transparent options else you won't be able to add that Shadow Plane correct? So here is my Solution:
For the first layer enable Environment Pass and then add it in the compositor like this:
[image]